# How to fix flipped and jumping touch screen and flipped orientation sensor after a driver update

Tags: touchscreen, sensors, orientation

After a Windows reset of a Windows tablet, it automatically updated the driver and I don’t have a backup for drivers.

The new drivers make the touch screen and orientation sensor completely unusable so I found the old one.

Now both are responsive but the touch screen have weird jumping issue:

It didn’t register the middle part. Also when I touch the bottom left, it shows I clicked the top right.

The orientation sensor got flipped too, ie: You rotate it upright, it shows upside-down, rotate it 90 degrees, the screen rotated 270 degrees.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details such as what make and model of Windows tablet you are using and what OS version and drivers are the “old” and “new” ones.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to edit the post after i solved it. I just install the oldest driver i could fine and this solved the problem

Comment: Please don’t edit your question to be “Solved.” I you have a solution, please post that as an answer and check it off as the answer.

Comment: Oh i dont realize i could answer my own question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for the oldest driver in the [Microsoft® Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com) and that fixed it.